# How to filter edited messages in telegram PTB?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

## Problem

1. I need to detect whether a message was edited in a specific group chat. Could it be similar to what I have already written down here?

   test_forward_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.chat(TEST_SENDER) & Filters.edited_message, forward_to_group)
2. If there is a way to filter edited messages, am I able to use it as a string to `lower()` and `split()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, that's exactly how it works, see [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.edited_message)
2. `update.{effective/edited}_message.text` contains the message as a string analogously to `update.(effective_)message.text` in the case of a new message.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: Odd it's telling me `AttributeError: type object 'Filters' has no attribute 'edited_message'`

How do I properly write this handler to have the filter?
`member_forward_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.chat(TEST_SENDER) & filters.edited_message, forward_from_members)`

`dispatcher.add_handler(member_forward_handler)`

Comment: Ah, my bad. It's `Filters.update.edited_message`

Comment: ok so I did the following
1. Made filters into this `Filters.chat(TEST_SENDER) & Filters.update.edited_message`
2. made the reply function like this `sample_text2 = update.edited_message.text`

But it gave me a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'chat_id'` when I sent a message in the gc then edited it

Comment: NEVERMIND I fixed it by making the forward_message arguments also edited_message instead of just message as you can see here `bot.forward_message(chat_id = TEST_RECEIVER,
                                    from_chat_id=update.edited_message.chat_id,
                                    message_id=update.edited_message.message_id)`